# Pass str to .Site.GetPage in hugo

Tags: hugo

Within Hugo, I want to loop over a slice of strings and later use the current string to call `.Site.GetPage`.

Currently I receive the following error:

```
execute of template failed at <.Site.GetPage>: can’t evaluate field Site in type string
```

My code looks like this:

```
{{ $array := slice "foo" "bar" "bam" }}
{{ range $array }}
    {{ $imgStr := printf "%s" ".jpg" | printf "%s%s" . | printf "%s%s" "images/" | printf "%s" }}
    {{ $img := resources.Get $imgStr }}
    {{ $imgSrc := $img.RelPermalink }}
    {{ with .Site.GetPage . }}
         <h1>{{ .Title }}</h1>
         <img src="{{ $imgSrc }}">
         <p>{{ .Content }}</p>
    {{ end }} 
{{ end }}
```

I tried to cast the type of `.` to Site. How can I use the string that is stored within `.` to call `.Site.GetPage`?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the range, `.` refers to the current value of the array being read. You need to use `$.` instead of `.` to [access the global context](https://gohugo.io/templates/introduction/#2-use--to-access-the-global-context):

```
{{ $array := slice "benefits" "faq" }}
{{ range $array }}
    {{ with $.Site.GetPage . }}
         <h1>{{ .Title }}</h1>
         <p>{{ .Content }}</p>
    {{ end }} 
{{ end }}
```